# Llenar select desde carpeta

Tags: php, html, joomla3

Tengo un archivo `index.php` dentro del cual tengo mi `select` y deseo llenarlo con los archivos de una carpeta especifica, pero obtengo como resultado dos puntos `..` como se muestra en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código.**

```
<select name="Combobox1" size="1" id="cmbimgprin" style="position:absolute;left:441px;top:377px;width:468px;height:28px;z-index:2;">
    <option>Seleccione una Opción...</option>
    <?
    $directorio = "D:\letritastv\imagenes";
    $sizekb = 0.0 ;
    $sizemb = 0.0 ;
    $dir=opendir($directorio);
    $file=array();
    while (($file = readdir($dir))!== false)
    {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
    {  
    ?>        
        <option><? $file?></option>      
    <?}}?>
 </select>
```

> ¿Que falta o sobra en este código?

Comment: Podrías intentar abrir la etiqueta `PHP` como normalmente se hace `<?php   ....  ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un posible fallo puede ser la apertura de la etiqueta `PHP` , lo normal sería `<?php ... ?>` *(a menos que tenga una configuración adicional)*

Puede evitar tantas aperturas y cierre de llaves para evitar confusión y posibles errores de sintaxis , imprimiendo el `option` directamente con `echo`

Su código quedaría así :

```
<?php 
 $directorio = "D:\letritastv\imagenes";
 $dir=opendir($directorio);
 while (($file = readdir($dir))!== false)
  {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')       
        echo '<option>'.$file.'</option>';      
  }
?>
```

> Como aporte adicional podría leer sobre la función
>   [scandir($directorio)](http://php.net/manual/es/function.scandir.php)

Comment: estimado he intentado con su respuesta he puesto todo dentro de las etiquetas y no he tenido ningún resultado ni si quiera los dos puntos .. con la opción scandir tampoco me ha resultado...

Comment: Cambio las aperturas del tag `php` ? , o intentó con mi código tal cuál  ? , **mi código es funcional , comprobado**, sería conveniente que inspeccione su `html` con `F12`, a ver si le muestra algún mensaje de error de `PHP`

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono perfecto, la llamada a la web estaba errónea de mi parte, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con algo más similar a ésto:

```
<select name="s1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
  <?php 
       foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/*') as $filename){
       $filename = basename($filename);
       echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
    }
?>

</select>
```

[FUENTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177524/populate-a-select-list-from-a-directory-on-my-server-using-php-and-html)